# Excel formula for recommending a value based on a dynamic set of rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am not sure if this specific question has been asked but I am wondering if anyone can help me with this.

| **Sale Price** | 9.98 | Fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Expenses %** | 0.35 | Fixed |
| **Expenses** | 3.49 | Sale Price * Expenses % |
| **Cost** | 4.99 | Fixed |
| **ROI %** | 0.40 | Dynamic |
| **Adjusted Cost** |  | Result |

[image: Here is data needed to get result]

Basically what we want to achieve is a cost recommendation based off of the ROI %, so as you change the ROI % then the Cost Adjustment should also change to be true if you took Sale Price - Cost - Expense.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please improve your post by a) explaining the calculations, b) showing your attempts, c) showing the desired output, d) tell us, where you got stuck and e) by asking a specific question. By the way, StackOverflow is a community that helps coders that are stuck, it is not a plattform to request a script from scratch.

Comment: Is the ROI and input? It says dynamic which implies it's a formula? and is the recommended cost supposed to go next to "Adjusted Cost"? Do you calculate ROI as (Sale - Cost - Expenses) / Sale?

Answer (score 1):

Calc for `ROI` = `( Sale - Expense - Cost) / Sale`

In the area where you have `Adjusted Cost`, where I figure you're trying to calculate what Cost you need for a 40% ROI. I'm assuming your ROI is a manual input.

`Cost = [Sale Price] * ( 1 - [ROI] ) - [Expense]`